# Updated to 21.04, VLC stopped working but worked in 20.10. Mplayer does

Tags: networking, video, vlc

Used to open a security camera (EZVIZ) with VLC in 20.10 with the command:

````
    rtsp://192.168.1.200:554
    It fails and the log file says:
    satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session
    satip error: Failed to teardown RTSP session
    ```

nmap shows the device is present:
````

````
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-05-15 10:03 BST
Nmap scan report for TL-WA850RE.broadband (192.168.1.200)
Host is up (0.032s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
554/tcp  open  rtsp
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8200/tcp open  trivnet1
9010/tcp open  sdr
```

mplayer works but gives error messages:

```
mplayer rtsp://admin:******@192.168.1.200:554
MPlayer 1.4 (Debian), built with gcc-10 (C) 2000-2019 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing rtsp://admin:******@192.168.1.200:554.
Resolving 192.168.1.200 for AF_INET6...

Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: 192.168.1.200
Connecting to server 192.168.1.200[192.168.1.200]: 554...

librtsp: server responds: 'RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'
rtsp_session: unsupported RTSP server. Server type is 'unknown'.
libavformat version 58.45.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
````

```
Apparently something has changed between 20.10 and 21.10 that is affecting VLC.  I've tried various changes to the input/Codec settings that have been suggested on different websites but no effect.
Any ideas?
Thanks

When I run cvlc --no-one-instance -vv rtsp://192.168.1.200:554 on my desktop it just hangs:
VLC media player 3.0.12 Vetinari (revision 3.0.12-1-0-gd147bb5e7e)

When I run it my laptop, also running ubuntu 21.04, it gives this error message:

    [00007f00e0000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
    [00007f00e0000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
    [00007f00e0000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
    [0000563550b15a50] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
    [0000563550b15a50] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: connection succeeded (socket = 12)
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9338
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9339
    [00007f00e80015e0] satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session
    [00007f00e80015e0] satip stream error: Failed to teardown RTSP session
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: net: connecting to 192.168.1.200 port 554
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: connection succeeded (socket = 11)
    [00007f00e80015e0] access_realrtsp stream warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
    [00007f00e80015e0] access_realrtsp stream debug: rtsp connected
    [00007f00e80015e0] access_realrtsp stream warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
    [00007f00e80015e0] main stream debug: no access modules matched
    [00007f00f4000c80] main input error: Your input can't be opened
    [00007f00f4000c80] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.200:554'. Check the log for details.
    [0000563550ad1940] main playlist debug: dead input
    [0000563550ad1940] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
    [0000563550ad1940] main playlist debug: nothing to play
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360613/unable-to-play-any-rtsp-streams-in-xubuntu-and-debian?

Comment: Still waiting for a `vlc` fix: Vetinary (3.0.18) does not work for me... `ffplay` and `totem` work just right though.

Answer (score 4):

To get this working try the snap install.

RTSP streams would not work locally for me either. According to this post, [Unable to play any rtsp Streams - in XUbuntu and Debian](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360613/unable-to-play-any-rtsp-streams-in-xubuntu-and-debian), Debian VLC builds do not support RTSP.

Here are directions for the snap [install](https://snapcraft.io/install/vlc/ubuntu)

Comment: VLC is currently broken in Debian 11, the snap version worked. Just had to create a script /usr/bin/vlc that runs "snap run vlc $*"

Comment: Things like this are why Linux will never be a mainstream desktop OS. You can't just break a core user scenario and leave it broken for over a year. Telling people to use a different package manager to acquire a fixed version isn't a practical workaround for 99.9% of humans.

Comment: If you don't want to go down the snap route, you may consider using mplayer instead. I use Linux Mint 21, and the included mplayer was able to play rtsp streams with no issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to run from terminal with increased verbosity to see what happening:

```bsh
cvlc --no-one-instance -vv rtsp://...
```

But your url looks not proper to me. Shouldn't rtsp urls be in the form like `rtsp://host:port/path.sdp`? Or you probably messed protocol and it should be `rtp://` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned debian\ubuntu vlc builds are not including vlc anymore.

It is a huge overhead, but the Nix package is working for me:

```
nix-shell -p vlc --command "vlc rtsp://192.168.1.137/ch0_0.h264"
```

You have to install the nix package manager before :
https://nixos.org/download.html#download-nix

Answer (score 0):

May be late on  this one, but a fix for vlc, install a later version. I had the same problem with Linux Mint 21.1 (based on ubuntu 22.04). Could not stream video from cctv cameras that worked fine with LM20 (ubuntu 20.04).

[download for ppa:](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/vlc3)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/vlc3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Worked for me, seems vlc 3.0.16 is broken, the ppa installs 3.0.18.

Comment: Still waiting for a `vlc` fix: Vetinary (3.0.18) does not work for me... `ffplay` and `totem` work just right though.