# Unable to play any rtsp Streams - in XUbuntu and Debian

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, rtsp

I am unable to play any RTSP-Stream from any XUbuntu/Ubuntu/Debian Live-Stick or my XUbuntu which is running on my Laptop and Desktop.

I have several rtsp-sources:

- an RTSP-Stream on my local RaspBerryPi (authentication is not needed)
- a stream from the internet (authentication is not needed)

Both streams can be played with VLC on:

- my other RaspBerryPi (RaspBerryPi OS)
- my Windows-Laptop
- the Android Tablets, my mobil-phone
- XUbuntu 20.04 Laptop and Desktop-PC

Both streams can **not** be played with VLC/mplayer/ffplay on:

- my XUbuntu **21.04** Laptop, XUbuntu **21.04** Desktop
- with Debian **11**
- Ubuntu 21.04, XUbuntu 21.04 Live-Version (which I have tried to have a clean system)

The problem must be the new base of Ubuntu, the new Debian 11, because there it is not possible too, to open the stream.

I get a error-mesage like this in VLC:

```bash
satip debug: try to open 'rtsp://192.168.178.2:8554/video0'
satip debug: connect to host '192.168.178.2'
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.178.2 port 8554
...
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 37)
main debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9040
main debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9041
qt debug: IM: Setting an input
satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.178.2 port 8554
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 36)
access_realrtsp warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
access_realrtsp debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
```

I have tried it with mplayer, vlc (3.012 in the Pi and Linux, the App version is 3.3.4 ), ffmpeg ... but the result is the same.

This means, the problem is not VLC.

Are ports blocked in Ubuntu/Debian or is there something special I have to do, so that I can play rtsp-steams?

Comment: Still waiting for a `vlc` fix: Vetinary (3.0.18) does not work for me... `ffplay` and `totem` work just right though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=158071&p=520527 says:

> Please note that Debian VLC builds do not support RTSP by Debian policy decision. Use the Flatpak if you need RTSP.

Maybe "use the Flatpak" or "Snap, but not .deb's" helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is working very well. I do not understand why Debian have these restrictions, but it is good to find a way around. I mean, it works every else, why not with Debian? (licence trouble?)

Comment: Debian maintainers have a history of weird decisions and I'm really glad people came up with snap to overcome weird debian maintainer's decision, which affect our lives... I think we should be able to have a control over what we want on our machines, and not some random people out there who find it suitable to decide something is not good for us...

Comment: Please note that snap has issues with NFS based home directories.